# [Java][Spring] Insert query executed without error but data did not inserted

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have java application that execute native query, I have tried to execute the query using entityManager.createNativeQuery, jdbcTemplate, and java.sql.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate, none succeeded. The query completed without error, but no data is inserted.

Here's my actual SQL:

```
WITH stmt AS (
    INSERT INTO account_statements (
                                    amount,
                                    sum_amount,
                                    available_balance,
                                    previous_available_balance,
                                    hold_amount,
                                    previous_hold_amount,
                                    type,
                                    note,
                                    partner_id,
                                    incoming_transfer_id
        )
        (
            SELECT
                ?,
                ?,
                (available_balance + ?),
                available_balance,
                hold_amount,
                hold_amount,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?::uuid,
                ?::uuid
            FROM account_statements
            WHERE partner_id = ?::uuid
            ORDER BY created_at
                DESC LIMIT 1
) RETURNING id, available_balance, hold_amount), debit AS (
    INSERT INTO journals (
                          amount,
                          type,
                          account_name,
                          account_statement_id,
                          partner_id
        ) (
            SELECT
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    id,
                    ?::uuid
            FROM stmt
                 )
), credit AS (
    INSERT INTO journals (
                          amount,
                          type,
                          account_name,
                          account_statement_id,
                          partner_id
        ) (
            SELECT
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    id,
                    ?::uuid
            FROM stmt
                 )
)
UPDATE partners
SET
    available_balance = (select available_balance from stmt),
    hold_amount = (select hold_amount from stmt)
WHERE id = ?::uuid;
```

Not sure what I did wrong, but when I tried the SQL above in pg console and replace all the placeholders, it worked. Does anyone have an idea why the SQL above is not working?

Comment: why are you doing this complex logic in one query, can you break it down in smaller chunks? It would be lot easier to debug... also you should post your Java code please...

Comment: We also don’t know what is the nature of `journals` and `account_statement`. Are they tables? Or objects instance in plsql or psql or what? And why are you trying to insert into two entities and update another with in a single statement.

Comment: If you get positive return value after executed java.sql.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate, your problem is database transaction not committed. Connection.setAutoCommit(true) may solve your problem. If executeUpdate returns 0, your problem may be wrong parameter values or SQL syntax.